# How to force all new window as new tab in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

My company has a intranet web site, all link will open a new window.
I have to use "Show as tab" one by one. And, the right-click menu and middle-click have been re-writen, so I cannot use right-click->Open link in new tab/middle-click to do it.

So, is there any method or extension, can force new windows as new tab?

Comment: Hold CTRL as you click on the link ?

Comment: @Lawrence Wow! It works! Including the search form. Thank you very much.

Comment: @KevinPanko That is totally different. The OP **wants** new tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold CTRL as you click on the link to open links in new tabs.